# Presentation MathML: How to place carryovers of long addition of decimal numbers in Elementary Math correctly?

Tags: math, addition, presentation, mathml

I am trying to generate MathML according to Elementary Math for Long Addition. From the examples from [W3 website](https://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter3.html#presm.elementary), there are just only the assignments without decimal point, e.g.

```
<mstack>
  <mscarries crossout='updiagonalstrike'>
    <mn>2</mn>  <mn>12</mn>  <mscarry crossout='none'> <none/> </mscarry>
  </mscarries>
  <mn>2,327</mn>
  <msrow> <mo>-</mo> <mn> 1,156</mn> </msrow>
  <msline/>
  <mn>1,171</mn>
</mstack>
```

This will represented as: [image]

So, I just created my own MathML file containing numbers with decimal points. My MathML is:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mstack>
    <mn>789.255</mn>
    <msrow>
       <mo>+</mo>
       <mn>56.86</mn>
    </msrow>
    <mscarries>
       <mn>1</mn>
       <mn>1</mn>
       <mn>1</mn>
       <mn>1</mn>
       <none/>
       <none/>
    </mscarries>
    <msline/>
    <mn>846.115</mn>
  </mstack>
</math>
```

And the result is: [image]

You can see that the carryovers are not placed correctly. They begin in front of (invisible) decimal point to the left, instead of beginning from the most-right column to the left.

Anyone has any idea how can I place those carryovers correctly using Elementary Math according to MathML? (I also tried to use `stackalign='right'` as an attribute of `mstack` but it doesn't look good either.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What rendering engine are you using?

Comment: Also, carries have to come before the line they affect.

Comment: Yes, you are right about placing `mscarries` before the associated line, but in my case I try to represent the maths according to Austrian math schoolboks (which looks like above). I tried to place the `mscarries` before the first line, too. But it doesn't change anything.

I use the Java library called fmath from this website: http://www.fmath.info/formula/java/how_to_use.jsp#mathml

Comment: You specify position via the `position` attribute of the `mscarries` element. `s` (south) would be what you're after. But fmath doesn't seem to support it. Also, you should tag this question fmath.

Comment: Correction. The attribute is `location`, not `position`.

Comment: Thank you @PeterKrautzberger for your suggestion. I actually tried the option `location='s'` in `mscarries` already, but it didn't change anything. Since you said fmath may not support this, do you have another MathML 3 renderer that can do it? And maybe you want to write your answer in the answer box, so that I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no web-based MathML renderer supports the so-called "elementary math" section of MathML 3 well enough.

As mentioned in the comments, [fmath](http://www.fmath.info/formula/java/how_to_use.jsp#mathml) does not seem to support `location="s"`.

[WIRIS](http://www.wiris.com/editor/demo/en/) is closest (with minor visual glitches), [MathJax's experimental extension](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/mathml.html#experimental-mml3-extension) has trouble with this (due to its hacky `msline` trick) but can get it roughly right.

Unfortunately, they differ in bugs so here's one MathML sample for each.

The following works well in WIRIS (but not MathJax):

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mstack>
    <mn>789.255</mn>
    <mscarries location="s">
       <mn>1</mn>
       <mn>1</mn>
       <mn>1</mn>
        <none/>
       <mn>1</mn>
        <none/>
        <none/>
    </mscarries>
    <msrow>
       <mo>+</mo>
       <mn>56.86</mn>
       <none/>
    </msrow>
    <msline/>
    <mn>846.115</mn>
  </mstack>
</math>
```

The next one works roughly ok with MathJax (with the mml3 extension, e.g., use http://codepen.io/pkra/pen/QwbJWa) but not WIRIS.

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mstack>
    <mn>789.255</mn>
    <mscarries position="-2" location="s">
       <mn>1</mn>
       <mn>1</mn>
       <mn>1</mn>
        <none/>
       <mn>1</mn>
    </mscarries>
    <msrow>
       <mo>+</mo>
       <mn>56.86</mn>
       <none/>
    </msrow>
    <msline/>
    <mn>846.115</mn>
  </mstack>
</math>
```

Disclaimer: I'm part of the MathJax team.